# Why a "generic" MessageBodyReader/Writer implementation is not been called?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

i wrote this MessageBodyReader to match with any type of object, but it isn't been called. The json-b default implementation try to parse the string to object but it gives an error when try parsing a date, that i mapped with jackson annotations, this show that my MessageBodyReader is not called.

```
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JacksonMessageBodyReader implements MessageBodyReader {

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object readFrom(Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(entityStream, type);
    }

}
```

and here a simple resource.

```
@Path("/visits")
public class VisitResource {

    @Inject
    Repository<Visit> repository;

    ....

    @POST
    public Response post(Visit visit) {
        repository.create(visit);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: for me, there is no need to implement `JacksonMessageBodyReader` in your project, the only thing you need to do is to add [Jackson JAX-RS provider](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/) to your classpath. Which build tool you are using?

Comment: gradle, but if I only add this, will work automatically? will override the json-b default provider used? @A.Henteti

Comment: this what they told in their documentation: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/#usage-registering-providers :)

Comment: this is really nice, thanks my friend, but you know why this impl does not works?

Comment: Check there annotations are from correct package. Also check that you're request declares correct content type header